# React как сделать переход на карточку товара в интернет магазине

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста как при клике на карточку товара сделать на нее переход.
Карточки создаются динамически

```
{filteredCard.slice(0, this.state.visiable).map((item) => (
        <div className="card" key={shortid.generate()}>
         ......
        </div>
           )};
```

Данные беру с json. В карточке есть кнопка подробнее. По клику как отрендерить ее?
Подскажите пожалуйста)
В какую сторону двигаться мне

Comment: При клике берешь `id` карточки.Отправляешь запрос по этой `id` получаешь данные и рендеришь новую страницу с этими данными.

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы переходить на каждую уникальную карточку, в твоем случае тебе нужно использовать 'react-router-dom'.

```
{filteredCard.slice(0, this.state.visiable).map((item) => (
    <div className="card" key={shortid.generate()}>
      <NavLink to={'/название url/' + item.id}>{item.имя}</NavLink>
    </div>
       )};
```

В App Js:

```
<Route path="/название url/:id" render={() => Здесь компонента твоей карточки} />
```

В самой компоненте получаешь **props** и используешь то что тебе нужно.

Вот более детальное объяснение [перейти по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666263/hot-to-make-unique-navlink-for-each-element-in-react)